# I want to communicate with kernel to set up SADB in Android NDK but getting Permission Denied Error

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk

I am using following code and getting permission denied error.

```
if ((mSockFd = socket(PF_KEY, SOCK_RAW, PF_KEY_V2)) < 0) {
                LOGE("IPSec Init : PF_KEY socket creation failed");
                LOGE("mSockFd : %d, Error no : %d",mSockFd,errno);
                LOGE("Error String : %s",strerror(errno));
            }
```

I have added following permission in `AndroidMenifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Where

> PF_KEY is a new socket protocol family used by trusted privileged
>   key    management applications to communicate with an operating
>   system's key    management internals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open SOCK_RAW type socket you need to have root privileges. If you are trying to run this on Mobile then phone must be rooted. Or try to implement in Linux Machine you will get root privilege easily.